# Jena3 publishing explicit datatype in Virtuoso

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena, virtuoso

I have a service that creates a Jena3 `org.apache.jena.rdf.model Model` and then this is uploaded to a Virtuoso RDF Store. Values of properties within the model are created with the `.addProperty(String, String)` method, so that values need to be stored as Strings (as far as I know).

If this model is stored in an RDF and then uploaded to Virtuoso via `isql` commands, results are shown as follows:

```
?result
"3"
"21"
```

But, if the model is puloaded vía `Virtuoso Jena`, results show the datatype:

```
?result
"3"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
"21"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

Is there any way I can avoid uploading this datatype publication?

I am using the **Rapidminer SPARQL operator** to query Virtuoso, so that it makes less straightforward obtaining for values as integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to disable RDF 1.1, see why [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/migrate_jena2_jena3.html#rdf11-plain-literals)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do I have to disable it on the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint or when I am uploading it with Jena? And how do I do that?

Comment: `JenaRuntime.isRdf11 = false;` will change the behaviour of the RDF writer

Comment: It's no a writer issue (the literal would be written without xsd:string and work in an RDf 1.0 system). The created model has xsd:string literals (correct RDF 1.1) and it looks like the Virtuoso adapter passes on the xsd:string and the server is not RDF 1.1. If you set `JenaRuntime.isRdf11 = false` before creating the data, it may work.

Comment: What does "this model is stored in an RDF and then uploaded to Virtuoso via `isql` commands" mean? I.E., what is "an RDF" and what iSQL commands did you use? Also, how are you "uploading via Jena", and exactly how are you querying? The more you leave ambiguous, the less likely anyone can provide the answer you need. (Two more thoughts — [1] Result output format may impact whether you get these literals with explicit or implicit typing. [2] Exact versions of everything — Virtuoso, Jena Provider, JDBC Driver, Jena 3, RapidMiner Studio, RapidMiner Linked Open Data Extension — may matter.)